# AS3 passing Class in constructor's parameter but is Null(?)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, constructor

I am trying to add two objects to the stage with the main document's code. In the second added object, I'm trying to add the first object's class as a parameter to the second object. That way the second object (the intro) can do its functions first before moving to the core of the game (the first object). However, the object sent to the parameter appears to be null or has no direct connection to the first object's class (as in I can't modify any of the first object's variables with the second object or change its visibility, etc).

`Main Document's code :`

```
//first object :            
            var gameScreen = getDefinitionByName("Game") as Class;
            gameScreen.x = 0;
            gameScreen.y = 0;
            addChild(new gameScreen() as DisplayObject);

//second object :
            var introScreen = getDefinitionByName("Intro") as Class;
            introScreen.x = 0;
            introScreen.y = 0;
            addChild(new menuScreen(gameScreen) as DisplayObject);
            gameScreen.visible = false;
    //the goal is to make gameScreen not visible, but it is still visible
```

There's no real code in the first object's class that affects this process.

`Intro's code (second object) :`

```
private var game:Class;
public function Intro(screen:Class) 
{
    game = screen;
    game.visible = false; // game = first object
    //game is still visible after this code is run
}
```

Any clue on how to fix this? Or is there no solution. A work-around would be to put the intro (secondobject) integrated as a part of the game (first object). Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're approaching these classes in the way you have, but you can address them directly.  You also don't have to zero out their `x, y` values since (as a DisplayObject) they are defaulted to zero anyway.

```
var gameScreen:Game = new Game();
addChild(gameScreen);

var introScreen:Intro = new Intro();
addChild(introScreen);

// When you're ready to hide it, simply remove from the DisplayList
removeChild(gameScreen);
```

Hiding (or adding/removing) the `gameScreen` in this example is also confusing.  As one code block, it'll create and hide it in one go, which beckons the question: why are you adding it in the first place?

Your intro class:

```
package {
    public class Intro extends Game {
        public function Intro() {

        }
    }
}
```

All said, I'm still unclear what your actual goal in all of this is.  This much I can say, where you were attempting:

```
addChild(new menuScreen(gameScreen) as DisplayObject);
```

`menuScreen` is never imported.  `Intro`'s current code does accept a `Class` as its constructor argument, but you're not passing anything to the intro class, nor are you instantiating it.

---

### Addendum

Code in a class is run if it is directly invoked (e.g., `Math.floor()` is a function in the Math class, but you don't have to instantiate it first to use it), or when you instantiate the Class (in this case, its constructor is run).  This does not require adding it to the DisplayList (i.e., Stage) for the code to run; showing it on screen is an afterthought at that point.

Assume we have a class called "Foo":

```
package {
    public class Foo extends Sprite {
        import flash.events.Event;

        public function Foo() {
                trace("Constructor called.");
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, saySomething);
        }

        public static function bar():void {
                trace("You can call me anytime.");
        }

        private function saySomething(e:Event):void {
                trace("You can only call me from within the class.");
        }
    }
}
```

We could first call `bar()` on the class, without instantiating it.  We could then also instantiate a copy of it, and the constructor will be called.  But neither operation requires parenting it to the stage.

```
import Foo;

Foo.bar() // traces: "You can call me anytime."
var myThing:Foo = new Foo(); // traces: "Constructor called."
addChild(myThing); // traces: "You can only call me from within the class."
```

To answer your question, [`import`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#import) is performed as demonstrated above, and its purpose is to "Make externally defined classes and packages available to your code." In addition to your other classes, you haven't shared what `menuScreen` looks like.  Which leads me back to my original question: what exactly are you trying to do?

That said, I hope this helps clarify how the code works.

Comment: Thanks for responding. If an object is removed `removeChild`, then it cannot run any of its actions? Or its constructor is run again when it is added? Otherwise, what is the difference between `objectName.visible` and `addChild(objectName)`?

You also said `menuScreen` was not imported and that I'm not passing anything into the class or instantiating it - I think these were the problems I wanted to address but couldn't find the words for them. How would I go about importing it or passing/instantiating it properly?

Comment: `menuScreen` is simply an interface-screen that has buttons - like a menu. So basically the user can navigate between different parts such as the `game` or `options` or etc. I don't yet want the game to start yet while the `menuScreen` is still visible to the player however I still have functions running on the `gameScreen` (first object) but I don't want the player to see the `gameScreen` which is why I want to set its visibility to `false`. I'll try your suggestion of importing the class tomorrow morning. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.